# How do I stop Chrome from pre-populating input boxes?

Tags: html, autocomplete, input, google-chrome

Is there some way I can stop Chrome from auto populating input boxes?  I have a page with a Sign Up form and a Log In form.  In Chrome, if a user has already signed up and they've come to this page to log in, the password input box on the sign up form is populated with their password.  I would really like to force the sign up fields to never auto complete.

I've tried setting autocomplete="false" but this makes no difference.

Comment: If the autocomplete answers below won't work, try something like value=" " (setting an empty string as default value). Even plugins/addons in chrome will not overwrite existing data in an input field.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`autocomplete="off"` worked on our site.

Comment: For reference (HTML5 Draft Spec - autocomplete): http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#attr-form-autocomplete, and it looks to be (at least partially) supported in most modern browsers.

Comment: That's in accordance with the documentation of this non-standard (until HTML5) attribute: "Any string other than off enables AutoComplete" according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx , the WebKit docs https://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocomplete and the Mozilla docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes

Comment: and autocomplete="off" works perfectly on ours now too!  Thanks for that.  I was sure I read that the attribute had true/false states.. Obviously I was wrong.

Comment: This solution does not work on modern browsers. Chrome just ignores "autocomplete" attribute.

Comment: This solution worked for me in November 2023 on both Chrome and Edge browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use different field names.

Comment: There is no guarantee this would work, and really I shouldn't have to refactor my form/dependencies to avoid it. In my case Chrome is autocompleting my username in a confirm email field with the name "registration_form[email][second]".  I'm not sure what I would even change it to in order to prevent this behavior. Chrome is autocompleting a field with a value that doesn't even meet the html5 input type=email requirements.  It overlooks the input with "_username" in the name, and then skips the first email input box to autofill the second confirmation input box.

Comment: Confirmed today this does not work with recent browsers. They quite happily attach to the first `type="text"` that comes before the first `type="password"` field.