# Autofill in two forms on one page?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I'm aware of this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23156578/32429), but my question is a bit different.

I have two unrelated forms on one page. One asks for a user name and password.  The other asks for an email address and password.

The problem is that Chrome autofills them both with the same id/pw combo.

How can I tell the browser that these are two separate id/pw combinations and should be remembered separately?

The id fields have different types, ids and names. The pw fields also have different ids and names.