# How to prevent Chrome from requesting to save credit card information

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete

I am trying to find a way to *programmatically* disable Chrome's "Do you want save this credit card info" prompt.

I have tried adding `autocomplete="off"` to all the inputs as well as the form, yet this prompt still comes up.

Is there a way to disable this programmatically?

Unfortunately, this is different from [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality) because this all revolves around tricking Chrome into thinking the input field is not a password field / simply using `autocomplete="off"`, however Chrome no longer acknowledges `autocomplete="off"`.

This is the banner I'm referring to:

[image: Do you want chrome to save your credit card information]

Comment: Name the field to something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Comment: Also answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191

Comment: almost the same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938891/disable-autofill-in-chrome-without-disabling-autocomplete

Comment: All those answers relate to text box password fields and suggest setting autocomplete="off" on the form.

OP is asking about credit card info in Chrome on a form that already has autocomplete="off". I am seeing the same behaviour and I agree with OP that Chrome is not acknowledging this and is offering autocomplete for credit card details even when the form specifies not to.

The other questions don't resolve this as they suggest things that OP has already tried and has stated aren't working.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

There's a good reason why Chrome ignores `autocomplete="off"` - it's not your information to decide whether or not the user's browser can save it. As such there is deliberately no way to disable this functionality programmatically.

You *can* make Chrome respect `autocomplete="off"` by setting the appropriate flag in `chrome://flags` which would give you the outcome you desire, but this only affects your browser - again, it's the user's information to decide to do with as they see fit.

Comment: I disagree.  I know my web page is asking a merchant for someone else's credit card number.  Chrome tries to auto-fill the current user's credit card number.  Which is useless and wrong.  I don't expect my users to have to mess around in chrome://flags.

Comment: Besides the tricks mentioned, perhaps you could permutate the fieldname (always attaching someRandomHash <input name="cardno5aCvG...   <input name="cardno8FHV48... - filtering (normalizing) that when processing the returned form values (there'll always be just one   (cardno.*)-value in the form, easily regExp-able...)

Comment: The problem is we had to comply with merchant's security requirement due to multiplying security breach by hackers in web browsers.  So it is a must.   Also we have a dealer that know every customer's credit card info which is a violation of merchant's security rule too.

Comment: The problem is the browser user may be an admin who's receiving credit card data over the phone.  In this situation the browser is prompting to save someone else's credit card data.  An obvious problem.

Answer (score 3):

What I did is using a hidden field for Credit Card Number and Save the actual credit card number in it then clear the actual Credit Card number from screen by JScript.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem you're experiencing; and with a newer browser version.

[image: Save card prompt]

To resolve this, you have to set autocomplete at form element.

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/cc.html" method="POST">
    <!-- Form fields -->
    <input type="text" name="cc" id="cc" />
    <!-- More form fields -->
</form>
```

For some reason **Google Chrome** ignores the `autocomplete="off"` at `<input type="text" />` for **Credit Card** prompts, but doesn't prompt when you set it with `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and had no success. The way I solved it, in the end, was actually to replace my label e.g. "Credit Card Number" with an image that contained the words "Credit Card Number", it worked a charm.

```
<div class="field">
   <div class="label">
      <img src="../images/cc-number.png">
   </div>
   <div class="value">
      <input type="text" name="ccnumber" id="ccnumber">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer trades one problem for another (accessibility), imho.