# how to remove form auto filling in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, autocomplete

I tried several examples, i found autocomplete off will do the requirment but even form has auto-complete=off input fields in the form getting fill by double clicking on the input.

Comment: share the code what you tried

Comment: In which browser are you testing this? If Chrome, you should be aware that Chrome's built-in Autofill option is separate from the standardised HTML autocomplete attribute. This SO question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938891/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" autocomplete="on">
 First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
 E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```