# Chrome 72.0 autocomplete disable textbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Chrome 72.0 not working autocomplete text

```
<input placeholder="" name="uname" type="text" style="display: none;">

<input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="uname" type="text" id="uname">
```

Any other solution for latest chrome 72.0?

Comment: Have you tried autocomplete="off"  in <input>.

Comment: Yes i already did it still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Set autocomplete to on and set the name of the input:

```
<input autocomplete="on" name="inputName">
```

Comment: i didn't want autocomplete on i want disable

Comment: so use `autocomplete="off"`, or try to use **autoComplete** istead, because **autocomplete** will not working in react for example

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't really want you to prevent autofill. It intentionally ignores any attempts to disable autocomplete.

But of course, there are some hacks. You can set such fields to `readonly`, and remove the attribute on either page load or focus. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28663166/2754871).

If you prefer a non-js solution, you can also add extra input elements to the form, and make them disappear with something like;

> position:absolute;top:-99999px;left:-99999px;

Yes, this is a dirty hack. But the old solution (using `display:none`) is not enough to cheat chrome anymore.